# Continuous measure $\mu:\mu(A_i)\in(0,\infty)$ for any finite collection of measurable, uncountable, infinite & bounded sets $A_i\subset\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{L})$ be a measurable space, where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra. Further, consider any finite collection of infinite, uncountable and bounded subsets $\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$ satisfying $A_i\in\mathcal{L}$ for all $A_i\in\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$. Then, **is it possible to find a measure $\mu$ which is continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure and satisfies $\mu(A_i)\in(0,\infty)$ for all $A_i\in\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$?**

***Disclaimer!** After not obtaining an answer for over two days, I have done my bit of research and have reformulated my question. Hence, the comments may no longer agree with the content of this question. Thank you to all of you who, through your comments, made me realise how bad my original question was. I hope the question is properly formulated now; but if it isn't, leave a comment and I'll keep working on it!*

Thank you all!

**ANSWER!** No, such a measure cannot be found. Since the Lebesgue measure assigns measure $0$ to some uncountable, infinite and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^N$ (i.e., consider for example the Cantor set), there exists some sequence $\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$ for which any measure $\mu$ that is continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure will satisfy $\mu(A_i)=0$ for some $A_i\in\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$.

Comment: "I think all bounded subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ are measurable" - This is not true. Second, if any of $A_i$ are singletons (in fact, if any are countable), this is not possible by countable additivity.

Comment: @Héctor : When you say that a set is measurable, you want measurability in which sens ? Lebesgue ? Borel ? something else ? Be more clear at this point.

Comment: In the compact case the answer is certainly yes, because all compact sets are Lebesgue measurable and Lebesgue measure is finite on bounded sets

Comment: @Héctor , You ask: "In other words: does a measure $\mu$ satisfying $\mu(A_i)<\infty$ for all $A_i\in\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$ as well as $\mu(\mathbf{x})=0$ for all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ always exist?"  The answer is yes. Just take $\mu$ to be identically zero.

Comment: **Thank you** all for your useful comments and for helping me realise how bad my original question was. I have now reformulated it --I hope it's understandable now.

Comment: I don't understand if you want, given aù family of subsets, a measure (on the whole $\mathcal L$?) such that et cetera, or if you want a measure (on $\mathcal L$?) such that for all finite families et cetera, as your objection to Lebesgue measure would suggest.

Comment: @Gae.S. **Thank you** for your comment. Although I'm not completely sure I'm understanding it, let me give it a try. The family of subsets $\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$ is given *ex-ante*. In other words: "given a family of subsets $\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$, I want a measure on the whole $\mathcal{L}$ such that [...]". However, I do not see how my objection to the Lebesgue measure is incompatible with this understanding of my question. What if the Cantor set belongs to this *ex-ante* family of sets $\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$? Then, my objection is still valid. Does this comment clarify your doubts?

Comment: @Héctor Because if you give me a finite family of subsets and I find you a measure such that yada yada yada number 1 (say, the Lebesgue measure) then it is entirely possible that some uncountable subset that isn't in the original collection will have measure $0$. So why does the existence of one such subset invalidate everything?

Comment: @Gae.S. **Thank you** again for your comment. I'm fine with sets outside my collection having (potentially) $0$ measure. However, suppose the Cantor Set $C$ belongs to my collection of subsets $\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$ (i.e., $C\in\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$. Then, $\lambda(C)=\lambda(A_i)=0$ for some $A_i$, thus invalidating the Lebesgue measure. I suspect that I'm missing something, but I can't really tell what it is...