# Three simple questions on measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

A couple of days ago, I posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4058074/are-bounded-subsets-of-mathbbrn-finitely-measurable-with-a-continuous-meas), which remains unanswered. The comments that I have received make me think that this is so because it is ill-defined. Hence, I post this other question with the hope of understanding the basics of measure theory so I can go back to the other question and edit it accordingly.

Let $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{A})$ be any measurable space. Then,

1. $X\in\mathcal{A}\Leftrightarrow X$ measurable.

Let $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{L})$ be a measurable space, where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lebesge $\sigma$-algebra. Then,

2. There exist two measures $\mu:\mathcal{L}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu':\mathcal{L}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\mu\neq\mu'$.

Let $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{L},\lambda)$ be a measure space where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Then,

3. $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ infinite and bounded $\Rightarrow \lambda(X)\in(0,\infty)$.

**Are (1), (2) and (3) true statements?** I think that (1) is true by definition of $\sigma$-algebra. I think that (2) is also true because as shown in the accepted answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4042924/examples-of-measures-that-assign-positive-measure-to-countable-sets-of-mathbb), one can define a measure that is not the Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{L})$. For (3), I do not have an intuition and I'm not sure whether it's true.

Thank you all!

**EDIT!** As noted in the comments, (3) is false. Hence, let me replace (3) for (3'). Let $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{L},\lambda)$ be a measure space where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Then,

3'. $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ infinite, **uncountable** and bounded $\Rightarrow \lambda(X)\in(0,\infty)$.

Comment: For (3) consider $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$

Comment: $1$ depends on your notion of measurable, unfortunately it is not a canonical notion (sometimes it depends on the extension to a complete space). $2$ and $3$ are obviously true.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow:  **Thank you** for your comment. Unfortunately, I'm not sure I'm getting your point. Could you please elaborate it further?

Comment: @John B **Thank you** for your comment. By 'measurable' I just meant that, given a measure $\mu$ on $(R^n,\mathcal{A})$, $\mu(X)$ is well defined.

Comment: The Lebesgue measure of a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is zero. Thus $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is a countably infinite and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure zero. This contradicts (3).

Comment: @MichaelMorrow **Thank you** for your comment. What if $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is not only infinite and bounded, but also uncountable?

Comment: In that case it can have positive measure. Take $[0,1]$ for example. It has Lebesgue measure $1$, and it is an uncountable bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow **Thank you** for your comment. It *can* have positive measure, or it *always* has positive measure?

Comment: It can also have zero measure. Google "cantor set".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In a measurable space $(Y,\mathcal A)$, the term $\mathcal A$*-measurable sets* indicates the elements of $\mathcal A$, and obviously the term is shortened to *measurable sets* when there isn't any ambiguity.
2. There are always at least two measures on a non-empty measurable space $(Y,\mathcal A)$: the zero measure and the restriction to $\mathcal A$ of the counting measure, namely $$\mu(X)=\begin{cases}\operatorname{card} X&\text{if }X\text{ is finite}\\ \infty&\text{if }X\text{ is an infinite set}\end{cases}$$
3. Some bounded sets aren't Lebesgue-measurable, therefore discussing their Lebesgue measure is somewhat idle talk (it's still possible to talk about their Lebesgue outer measure, but I digress). For Lebesgue-measurable subsets, $A\subseteq B$ implies $\lambda(A)\le\lambda(B)$ and therefore, since $\lambda(a,b)=b-a$, bounded Lebesgue-measurable subsets have finite Lebesgue measure. Obviously, countable additivity makes it so that countably infinite subsets are Lebesgue-null sets but, more to the point, [Cantor's set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) is a compact and uncountable Lebesgue-null set.